# Circumcenter of acute-$\Delta ABC$ is $O$. Line $AC$ intersects circumcircle of $\Delta AOB$ at point $X$, in addition to vertex $A$. Prove $XO⟂BC$.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, triangles, quadrilateral

**PROBLEM**
The circumcenter of an acute-$\mathtt{\Delta ABC}$ is $\mathtt{O}$. Line $\mathtt{AC}$ intersects the circumcircle of the $\mathtt{\Delta AOB}$ at a point $\mathtt{X}$, in addition to the vertex $\mathtt{A}$. Prove that the line $\mathtt{XO}$ is perpendicular to the line $\mathtt{BC}.$

**MY APPROACH**

- I claim that $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$ can't be equal because then there won't be two points as $X$ and $A$ that intersect the circumcircle of $\Delta AOB$.
- Construct the perpendicular bisector of side $BC$, it is clear that this goes through $O$.
- Let the point at which it intersect $BC$ be $P$ and the point at which it intersect $AC$ be $X'$.
- We know that $\angle BAC=2\cdot\angle BOC$ .The $\Delta BOP$ and $\Delta COP$ are congruent. Therefore we know that $\angle BOP=\angle BAC$, and $\angle X'OB=180^o -\angle BAC$.
- Thus, we conclude that $ABOX'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $X'$ also lies on the circumcircle of $\Delta AOB$. Therefore, $X=X'$, which means $OX$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

Is my Proof Correct?

Comment: How does showing that $\angle BOP = \angle BAC$ show that $ABOX'$ is cyclic? It would be better to show that $\angle AX'O = \angle ABO$ and then use converse of angles in the same segment to show that $X'$ lies on the circumcircle of $AOB$

Comment: Because when BOP=BAC ,X'OB=180 -BAC which means ABOX' is cyclic

Comment: That line of reasoning only works when $X'$ lies on the line **segment** $AC$ but $ABC$ is an acute triangle so this can't happen

Comment: Are you familiar with barycentric coordinates? They can work pretty well for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$X'$ is the point where $OP$ meets $AC$ (and $OX' \perp BC$)

$2\angle ACB = \angle AOB$ (angle at center is twice the circumference)

but $\Delta AQO \cong \Delta BQO$ by $SAS$
$\implies \angle AOQ = \angle BOQ$
$\angle AOQ + \angle BOQ = \angle AOB \implies \angle BOQ = \angle ACB$

Hence $\Delta CPX' \sim \Delta OQB$ by $AA$
$$\implies \angle AX'O = \angle ABO$$

By the converse of angles on the same segment $X'$ lies on the circumcircle of $\Delta ABO \implies X' = X$